# Custom Syntax Highlighter with Jekyll on Github Pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, rouge

How can I create a custom syntax highlighter to use with Jekyll on GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll 3 and above is using **[rouge (An elegant, extendable code highlighter written in pure Ruby.)](http://rouge.jneen.net/)**.
See also "[Syntax Highlighting in Jekyll](https://mycyberuniverse.com/web/syntax-highlighting-jekyll.html)".

In order to add a custom syntax highlighter, you submit a pull request to that project. As an example, consider the [PR 650: LiveScript support](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/pull/650/files), for [issue 309](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/issues/309).

Once that PR is merged, you can use it on GitHub pages.

---

Note 2022, as noted in [`rouge-ruby/rouge` issue 1902](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/issues/1902#issuecomment-1338634274):

> The old website `rouge.jneen.net` was deployed on the Heroku platform.  Since the Free tier has been retired, our application is no longer available. I believe [@jneen](https://github.com/jneen) is looking at hosting the site somewhere else.

Comment: end of 2022 and the Rouge link is broken (most likely because Heroku is no longer offering free tiers)

Comment: @J.R.BobDobbs Thank you for the update. I have edited the answer to explain the situation, as well as restored the deprecated link.